# Search input in Drupal 8

Tags: search

I have a website built in Drupal 8. 
In one of the basic page, I have to add a search box which searches only the contents in that specific page. 
Please suggest the best practice to implement this.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a view page, and in the FILTER CRITERIA you can add "for example" : content datasource:title and add the title of this specific page if it will not change
But the best is to use : ID = nid that you will find in your database in the
node_field_data table
Search for the title and you will find your ID and use it to filter in your views and that's it !